# Rearranging a 15 X 25 Excel matrix into three columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2003

In Excel I have data in cells from A1 to O5 (15 X 25).

I wish to rearrange things such that I have the following

```
  [A1][B1][C1]   
  [D1][E1][F1]   
  [G1][H1][I1]   
  [J1][K1][L1]  
  [M1][N1][O1]   
  [A2][B2][C2]   
  [D2][E2][F2]
```

...and so on.

I've tried and failed to find an elegant way to do this in Excel. Could someone please advise me?

I've seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/147492/transpose-matrix-style-table-to-3-columns-in-excel) but they seem to be playing a slightly different game there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a VBA shot:

```
Option Explicit

Sub rearrange()
Dim aValues As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim lRow As Long

'store the values in an array
aValues = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:O5").Value
lRow = 1

With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    For i = 1 To UBound(aValues, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(aValues, 2) Step 3
            .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = aValues(i, j)
            .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = aValues(i, j + 1)
            .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = aValues(i, j + 2)
            lRow = lRow + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: successful test +1

Answer (score 2):

Does this meet your needs?

- Set E21 to `=INT((ROW(A1)-1)/5)`
- Set F21 to `=MOD(ROW(A1)-1,5)`
- Set A21 to `=INDIRECT("R" & ($E21+1)&"C" & (COLUMN(A21)+$F21*3),FALSE)`
- Copy A21 to B21 and C21
- Copy A21:F21 down as many rows as required.
- Use Paste Special Values to convert A21:Cnn to values rather than formula.

Comment: This also has a successful test

Comment: I don't think the site allows me to tick both the suggestions, but they are both great. Thanks!

Comment: JMax posted his answer a few seconds before mine so it is fair he gets the points for an accepted answer.